# Sonarqube - see at what time was the analysis made

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to configure Jenkins with Sonarqube such that every time a new pull request is made, the code is analysed.

I'm looking at SonarQube and I'm not sure if the pull request was actually analysed or if it is an old analysis that I triggered manually.

I would like to know:

1.Can you see a list of analyses made by Sonarqube for a project, together with the time at which they were made?

2.Can you see which is the Git branch that has been analysed last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a given project, you can know the history of previous analyses:

- Prior to SonarQube 6.3, you need project admin rights and you can go to "Administration > History" page on your project to see all the past analyses with the exact time
- Staring with upcoming SonarQube 6.3 (to be released by the end of February 2017), any user will be able to see that "History" page with the details of previous analyses

About the 2nd point, it is not currently possible to know, from SonarQube Web UI, which Git branch (and commit) was analysed. But we will be working on this very soon.

Comment: I've logged in as `Administrator`(with the default `admin` username and `admin` password), I've clicked on `Administration`, but I can't see `History` anywhere. My version is 6.2

Comment: This is the "Administration" entry at project level, not the global one. See the following screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/APtvl0CWac9HWocGd2rCgQH7U5mlgL-tuqQ